# Delete Web Service client in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, webservice-client

Is it possible to delete web service client from the project in Eclipse?

I have deleted some generated META folders, but the structure of the project is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You just close the project from Eclipse and then delete the entire Web Service.